# Upgrade CE Magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

My site started life as version 1.6 and was upgraded a couple of years ago to 1.9.0.1. All appeared ok until the last security patches (others have been installed by others who are nolonger available).

I now want to Upgrade **CE Magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.1** can this be done in one step? In the past i have used connect manager to upgrade, however this is not showing any Magento version upgrades (i does show a couple of module upgrades but thats it).

**So my question is:**

1. Upgrade CE Magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.1 can this be done in one step?
2. How can i get the upgrade to show in connect manager?
3. Should i be upgrading using a different method?

Many thanks as i said its been a couple of years since i last had a lot of Magento involvement (due to ill health) so im a bit rusty. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

firstly backup yout site data and database

than copied fresh 1.9.3.1 magento and copied it to your  site data

than run your site and any error report generate than delete cache and report in var folder

and onse site running completely than check all functionality working fine or not

if any error than do the neccesary changes